# CSS dynamic value in angular

Tags: css, angular, dynamic, styles, rendering

How can I get a CSS in a string to dynamically paint an **HTML** element?

The HTML element must render a line of CSS code dynamically.
the use of `[style.etc]`, `[ngStyle]`, `[style]`, `[ngStyle]`, `[ng-class]` does not work for me because I receive a string with CSS code from the backend, example:

style: `"background: red; color: white;"`

I can not use the following solution:

**style: "{{style}}"** nor **[style] = "style"** because I get an alert in the console that says:

**WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value background: network; color: white;**

```
<button type="button"
  *ngFor="let controlHTML of buttons"
  style="{{controlHTML.attributes.style}}"> HelloWorld
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating method to bypass sanatizing unsafe will allow usage of stringed css

```
        <button type="button"
            *ngFor="let controlHTML of buttons"
            [style]="trustedSecurity(controlHTML.attributes.style)"> HelloWorld
        </button>
```

test button

```
         <button type="button"              
           [style]="trustedSecurity(style)"> HelloWorld
         </button>
```

test class with method that sanatizing unsafe value(css)

```
 import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

 export class TestClass{

   style = "background: red; color: white;";

   constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

   trustedSecurity(style) {
      return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
   }

}
```

Here you can read about creating safe pipes.

https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b

Answer (score 0):

you can also add:

```
     [style.background-color]="'red'"
     [style.color]="'white'"
```

If you want get color from some property in ts then remove ' characters and pass variable name e.g

```
     [style.color]="somePropertyWIthPrimaryColor"
```